# display current process stdout in PySide QTextEdit box

Tags: python, qt, stdout, pyside

I'd like to display all stdout from a python/PySide application in a QTextEdit box but all I can find is how to capture stdout from a subprocess. Is this even possible to to? Ideally I'd like to define some sort of call back that gets fired once anything is added to stdout so i dont need to loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can redirect stdout to some temporary file and then look in this file.

```
sys.stdout.close() 
sys.stdout = open("out.txt", "w")
```